# Oracle Pro*C SQL CONNECT gives a core dump

Tags: c++, sql, oracle

We currently build a C++ program using ProC and Oracle 12.1. At some point we do this :

```
int SQLMgr::GetAddInfo(char * SchemaName,char * DbName)                             
{                       
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;                                                 
    char lvcrSchemaName[20];                                                            
    char lvcrDbName[20];                                                                
    int  lvcrLicStatus;                                                                
    VARCHAR lvcrUsername[UNAME_LEN];                                                    
    VARCHAR lvcrPassword[PWD_LEN];                                                  
    VARCHAR lvcrBase[BAS_LEN];                          
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;                                                        

    EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO SQLError();

    oraca.orastxtf = ORASTFERR;                                                     
    lvcrUsername.len = strlen(strcpy((char *) lvcrUsername.arr, mstrUsername));     
    lvcrPassword.len = strlen(strcpy((char *) lvcrPassword.arr, mstrPassword));     

    lvcrBase.len = strlen(strcpy((char *) lvcrBase.arr, mstrBase));   

    printf ("GetAddInfo =[%s]\n",lvcrUsername.arr);
    printf ("GetAddInfo =[%s]\n",lvcrPassword.arr);
    printf ("GetAddInfo =[%s]\n",lvcrBase.arr);

    EXEC SQL CONNECT :lvcrUsername IDENTIFIED BY :lvcrPassword USING :lvcrBase;
    if (sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
    {
        printf("Connected\n");
    }

   (...)
```

This code works perfectly on our Dev Linux Red Hat machine but on our QA machine (Same Red Hat Linux 3.10.0 x86_64  and Oracle 12.1 ) we get a core dump right at the EXEC SQL CONNECT line.

I have checked the allocation of SchemaName and DbName, it's all fine.

If we look into the generated cpp file, the program crashes at the line :

```
sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn);
```

I don't understand what could be the difference between our machines (or systems) that could make this ProC program fail.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Are `SchemaName` and `DbName` being used somewhere?

Comment: Oh yes, what I wanted to say is "I have checked the allocation of mstrUsername, mstrPassword and mstrBase".  
SchemaName and DbName and strings to be returned. Right after the "connect" we have a sql query that put some values into SchemaName and DbName.   But I don't get there, it crashes at the connect line.

Comment: All of the `mstr` strings fit into their respective `VARCHAR` buffers without overflow?

Comment: Yes, it's the case. I found the problem. It was related to 32 bit binaries on Solaris. Nothing to do with Pro"C.

Comment: Good job, glad you got it resolved.